# How to remap "copy" shortcut in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am trying to tune the key bindings in Xcode (version 8)'s preference.

Most of the keybindings can be remapped without a problem, except the `Copy(Edit Menu)` command.

When I am trying to map the `copy` command to `Option+W` key combination, Xcode does not allow it and show warning:

```
Modifiers are reserved for alternates.
```

Is there a way to bypass this restriction? For example, are there any copy commands other than `Copy(Edit Menu)` that functions similarly? Or are there any hotkey script either at MacOS level or Xcode plugin level that can remap a keybinding to another?

(I am trying to map the copy command to `Option-W` because I have got quite used to this key from Emacs. )

Thank you.

Comment: @matt, questions about developer tools are on topic.

Comment: @KenThomases Fiddle-faddle. Suppose he'd asked how to delete Xcode from his computer. That's a "question about a developer tool" but you surely would not argue it's on topic. Conversely, the rules for what constitute a legal keyboard shortcut have _nothing whatever_ to do with Xcode.

Comment: while I agree with matt, here is a link to what may help others coming here looking for an answer: [https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32297/how-can-i-reassign-the-copy-paste-keyboard-shortcuts]

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS, Option-W is a typable character. It cannot be a hotkey. Hotkeys must include Command or Control.